# Identify points in Scatterplot (qplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to identify (means: show the observation number) some points in a Scatterplot (using qplot()) such as *identify* does for plot()?

Best regards, Sarah

Comment: pointLabel(x, y, labels = paste("  ", point_names, "  ", sep="") might work.  I am not sure.  That was suggested by somebody else as an answer here to a similar question.

Comment: Actually maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528709/how-to-add-labels-to-a-plot

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work for qplot(). Only for plot().

Comment: lattice, also based on grid graphics, has a `panel.identify` function. Maybe parts of it could be used (in conjunction with the recent discussion on grid.locator here) to provide a more general grid.identify that works with ggplot2.

Comment: It might be helpful trying `ggplot` in combination with function `ggplotly` form package `plotly` (example is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36184893/4783029))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this modified from the link I provided above

```
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10), label = seq(1:10))
ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() +
  geom_text(data = dat, aes(x,y, label = label), hjust = 2)
```

Comment: whoops.  That is ggplot.  Not qplot.  Same package, but different function.

Comment: And I think @Sarah is wanting to be able to click on points and have a label appear on them, as with `identify`.

Comment: Thanks for the current answers. 
@ joran: yes, that's exactly what I'm searching for!
@Mark Miller: Thanks, that may could help. The problem is, that the x and y coordinates are from different data.frames. But I'm working on this. But of course a solution like identify would be easier.

Comment: I solved the problem with the suggested code above! 
Thanks a lot for your help!