# Is there any way to use the Identify command with ggplot 2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In this case, everything is ok:

```
x <- 1:10 
y <- x^3
plot(x, y)
identify(x, y)
```

But, using qplot there are some troubles:

```
x <- 1:10 
y <- x^3
qplot(x, y)
identify(x, y)
```

Does anybody know a similar command or other way to label specific points in ggplot2 graphs?

Comment: A combination of `gglocator` from the `ggmap` package and `?geom_text` should give you what you want but not as nicely as identify.  You'l have to amke a data frame of x, y coords and text that you pass to `geom_text`.  If there's a better way I'd love to here it.

Comment: Thanks Tyler. I will try your combination!

Comment: @DaviMoreira, [would this work in your case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505495/identify-points-in-scatterplot-qplot/9505920#9505920)?

Comment: Tks Eric, but no. I really want to know if it is possible to select specific cases as can be done using the identify command.

Comment: `plotly::ggplotly()` may be useful. An example is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36184893/4783029).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a method that works using only the `grid` and `ggplot2` packages:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

x <- 1:10  
y <- x^3 
qplot(x, y) 

downViewport('panel-3-4')
pushViewport(dataViewport(x,y))

tmp <- grid.locator('in')
tmp.n <- as.numeric(tmp)
tmp2.x <- as.numeric(convertX( unit(x,'native'), 'in' ))
tmp2.y <- as.numeric(convertY( unit(y,'native'), 'in' ))

w <- which.min( (tmp2.x-tmp.n[1])^2 + (tmp2.y-tmp.n[2])^2 )
grid.text(w, tmp$x, tmp$y )
```

If you want a text label instead of the number your could replace `w` in the call to `grid.text` with something like `letters[w]` (or whatever vector of labels you want).

If you are going to be doing several of these then you could wrap this in a function with the last few lines possibly in a loop.  You could also add addtional logic to warn if you don't click near a point (like identify does) or to move the label closer or further from the point (this version places the label for the nearest datapoint at the point that you click).

Answer (score 15):

You may convert your plot, made with `ggplot2` to interactive graph by using function `ggplotly` from package `plotly`, e.g.:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

# Prepare data
x <- 1:10  
y <- x^3 
names <- paste("Point", LETTERS[x])

# Make a plot with `ggplot` as usual
qplot(x, y, label = names) 

# Convert it to interactive plot
ggplotly()
```

Then move your cursor over a point of interest and find information about it.

Answer (score 3):

I created a little work around to use the identify function within ggplot

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1.8,2.1,3.1,2.8,3.1,4.9,5.1,3.2,2.2),
    y=c(3.2,2.3,4.1,5.2,3.1,2,1.9,2.1,3),
    name=c('agw452','hhewhdsgwgb','cgahawrhs','gsarhrwhd','ehhrwhrwwrw','fhhrwwrw','ghhWwr','hhHRWRHwr','ihwhrHWRHw'))
plot(df$x,df$y)
identified <- identify(df$x,df$y,labels=df$name,pos=T)
df$pos <- NA
df[identified$ind,]$pos <- identified$pos
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() + 
    geom_point(data=subset(df,!is.na(pos)),aes(color='red')) +
    geom_text(data=subset(df,pos == 1),aes(label=name),vjust=1) + 
    geom_text(data=subset(df,pos == 2),aes(label=name),hjust=1) +
    geom_text(data=subset(df,pos == 3),aes(label=name),vjust=-.5) + 
    geom_text(data=subset(df,pos == 4),aes(label=name),hjust=0)
```

It uses the index and positions of your clicks and places the labels at the same positions as in the plot function...

hope that helps...

would be useful to have more positions then just 4... But don't know how to rewrite identify... yet ;-)