# Identifying individual plots in a Scatter Graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: Scatter Graph]

So right now I have a scatter graph with 80 plots that plots out data regarding music albums, my question is, is there any way to individually identify the plot? For example, when I click on the plot, it will tell me the name of the album.

I tried using the identify() command but it seems a bit glitchy right now and I kept getting "no data within 1 inches".

Comment: Do you want an interactive plot? maybe check the [plotly package](https://plotly.com/ggplot2/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to use the Identify command with ggplot 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526005/is-there-any-way-to-use-the-identify-command-with-ggplot-2)