# How to add labels to a scatter plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I am learning R and using ggplot2. I have tried this answer to solve my question but the labels don't appear, only numbers : [how to add labels to a plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528709/how-to-add-labels-to-a-plot)

I have three columns: One is called "Departamento" (that means the name of the state in my country), the second one is "Muertes.x.100.000" (that refer to deaths in population caused by cancer per every 100.000 inhabitants) and the third one is "Ingreso.Per.cápita.2.011" (that is the GDP per person in each state).

I got a correlation between number of deaths and gdp per person in 14 states but I want that each point in the graphic appear with the name of the state. My code is:

```
  ggplot(data=Top7DptosCancervsIngPercapita,aes(x=Ingreso.Per.cápita.2.011, y=Muertes.x.100.000))
  +geom_point(shape=1)
   +geom_smooth(method = lm,se=FALSE)
     +ggtitle("Los 7 Dptos con más y con menos muertes por cancer por 100.000 habitantes del 2.006 al 2.011 y su relación con el Ingreso Per cápita en 2.011")
```

Comment: I don't see in your code some of the solutions suggested in the link you provided.

Comment: Is the label column a factor? Check with `str(Top7DptosCancervsIngPercapita)` (for example)

Comment: See `geom_text` or `geom_label`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ggplot(data=Top7DptosCancervsIngPercapita,aes(x=Ingreso.Per.cápita.2.011, y=Muertes.x.100.000)) +
geom_point(shape=1) + geom_smooth(method = lm,se=FALSE)+
ggtitle("Los 7 Dptos con más y con menos muertes por cancer por 100.000 habitantes del 2.006 al 2.011 y su relación con el Ingreso Per cápita en 2.011")+
geom_text(aes(x=Ingreso.Per.cápita.2.011, y=Muertes.x.100.000,label=Departamento))
```

Comment: You're welcome! For the future however, always post your data with dput, it makes our life easier :)